# How to make IE recognise this .change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a jquery/javascript application.  Part of what I need is a file input, which I need to look the same across Firefox, Chrome, and (ugh) IE.  What I've done is made the file input hidden and placed a text box on top of it.  Then, I use jquery .click to make clicking the text box have the same effect as clicking the file input, and I use .change to make the contents of the file input show up in the text box.  Works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but the horrible horrible people at Microsoft want to ruin my day.

If anybody has the solution, I would be oh so grateful.  Thanks in advance!

```
<input type="text" id="fakefile">
<input type="file" id="realfile">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fakefile').click(function(){
        $('#realfile').click();
    });
    $('#realfile').change(function(){
        $('#fakefile').val($('#realfile').val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Which version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you provided a jsFiddle, other than simply HTML and Javascript. Anyways, `file` inputs can't always be `click`ed programmatically (as you see in IE). The way to get around this is (consistent across browsers) to position the `file` input on top of the textbox and set its opacity to 0. That way, when the user thinks they're clicking on the textbox, they're actually clicking on the `file` input and you don't have to do anything special in Javascript to trigger it.

Comment: I remember having a similar problem (but can't remember if it was for IE). I had to move the text input off the screen rather than hide it. For some reason hiding invoked some security issues.

Comment: Ian's suggestion seems better.

Comment: Ian's suggestion was how it initially was set up.  The problem I have is that management is requiring that the path be visible after the file is selected.

Comment: It's currently jquery 1.5.1.

Comment: @Ryan Trust me, it's the only way for it to be cross-browser compatible and consistent.

Comment: I actually ended up with a workaround that was a little too intense for what I was trying to accomplish.  I updated my jquery version and the .change and .click worked like I wanted them to, but ie wouldn't let me finish the upload for what I'm assuming is a security issue.  So i put in a jquery condition where if the browser is ie, it places the 0 opacity file input on top of the original input.  It still has the functionality of updating the text box, so I'm happy.  Thanks for the input everybody.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, you can do some hackyness and add a label to the file input and trigger the click on the label not the input but as soon as you try to submit the form it will simply fail in IE.

The way I solved the problem was to turn the file input opacity to 0 and absolutely position it over the styled element I want the user to think they are clicking.  This way they are in fact clicking the file input even though it appears they are clicking my styled element.

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fakefile').click(function(){
        $('#realfile').click();
    });
    $('#realfile').bind("change click", function(){
        $('#fakefile').val($('#realfile').val());
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deAf6/